# How to stop multiple inputs on single click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an onclick event and when i click on an object, i notice that if i use a console.log to check if i clicked, each click gives about 6 "hits" for the one click, how can i stop the propagation of clicks after the first so that only the event is only triggered once per click?

```
 var that = this; 
 var keys = [];
 var click = false;
 var canvas;
 var mEvent = null;

 document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     that.mEvent = e;
     that.click = true;
 });
 document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     that.click = false;
 });

 function mousedown() {
     return click;
 }
```

Comment: `mousedown()`? Parse error.

Comment: I just ripped it out of the typescript file i had, i made some changes to make it standalone hopefully.

Comment: Not reproducible. Click whatever element in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zwQX2/) and you will get only one hit per click

Comment: Same for me http://jsfiddle.net/fungku/rKwyM/ - behaves as expected...

Comment: Thanks guys, gonna go look deeper in my code, good to know that the code works fine and something else is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not happen. Make sure you are not registering these events from a function and calling that function multiple times.

Comment: thanks for saving me some work, i had it in a function but registered the listeners in the constructor but for some reason it was still called repeatedly, i called it directly now and all seems to be fine for now. one down, many to go! :D